# What the ‘typename’ mean in asio allocation exmple

Tags: c++, c++11, asio

the line 109 show in [asio allocation example](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.12.1/src/examples/cpp11/allocation/server.cpp)

```
template <typename T>
class handler_allocator
{

...

private:
  template <typename> friend class handler_allocator; // line 109

...

}
```

I wonder what the **template < typename >** mean ? Is it **template < typename T>** in commaon way? By the way, the example could work.

Comment: A class template with one type parameter is being made a friend; the parameter name is omitted. The point, it seems, is to make every instantiation of `handler_allocator` a friend of every other instantiation.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Template_friends

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`handler_allocator` is a *class template*, as in, only upon concrete instantiation it would result in an actual class. Hence, these instantiations are multiple, so you end up with one class per each `T`. In case you want to have these different classes a `friend` of each other then this line would be the way to go.

> I wonder what the template < typename > mean ? Is it template <
>   typename T> ... ?

Not quite. If you'd add the `T` then it would result in invalid code as this `T` would *shadow* the first `T`. You could add any other named identifier instead (let's say `S`) but it works without it either way as there's no use for it in this snippet.